# Can't reach File Server Cluster by DNS name

Tags: failovercluster, file-server, windows-cluster

I'm trying to set up a file server cluster so that it can be accessed by a standard DNS name on our domain. I've got a DNS A record set up, pointing `app.clusters.ourdomain.com` to the cluster service  IP address. When I ping the DNS name, it resolves to the proper IP address.
[image]

If I hit the file cluster UNC using the IP address, it works fine:
[image]

However if I try to hit it by the DNS name, then it finds no shares.
[image]

I **CAN** hit the C$ admin share using the DNS name though...
[image]

I've been googling, I found this answer that made kinda sense to me (thinking like header bindings on a site in IIS) https://argonsys.com/microsoft-cloud/library/how-to-configure-an-alias-for-a-clustered-smb-share-with-windows-server-2012/ , using PowerShell to add an Alias to the file server role. However when I try to add that DNS name in as an alias, it yells at me about it being in the wrong format.
[image]

I tried the alias both with and without quotes. And I know the cluster name is right, because I can successfully query the (no) Aliases for it without error.

The share was added via Cluster Manager, with no errors...
[image]

**How do I get the cluster to answer on that same IP address, when redirected there from a DNS name?**

windows Server 2016, with Failover Cluster Manager (2 nodes)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible. Aliases are 'old school' and also only work with NTLM. When using an SMB connection to an FQDN, it will probaly negotiate Kerberos auth which falls out of the alias scope.

Another option might be to add a secondary 'client access point' to your server ? It will require a separate IP though.